# How can I add spacing between <td> elements that use background and border without creating space between <th> elements?

Tags: html, css

I am working on my website and I have most of the design worked out, shown in the first image. I am trying to make the header row have no space (more accurately, make it look that way by having the image span across the entire row with no spaces.), but still have the elements themselves have space in between them.

Image showing a joined header, but separate body elements:

[image: Image showing a joined header, but separate body elements]

I am aware of the border-spacing css style, but it has to be applied to the table element, which means it will apply to headers and body elements. This with with a border-spacing set

Image showing what happens to the images when the border-spacing is set on the table:

[image: Image showing what happens to the images when the border-spacing is set on the table]

I did attempt to find an answer before posting and usually I find the answer fairly quickly, but this one seems to be a rare request. I prefer to avoid hacks if possible, but I will use them if its the only way. Also, if possible, I'd like it to be cross-browser capable. (changes to the solution are ok of course, just something that I can make work will all of them.)

I guess code is helpful to show. Here is the html:

```
<table id="users">
    <caption>Point Totals</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Xogue</td>
            <td>64433</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jesse</td>
            <td>104040</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nanokarp</td>
            <td>280</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brandon</td>
            <td>70</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
#users {
    border-spacing: 6px;
    width: 444px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 90px;
}

#users caption {
    background-image: url("_images/points_label.png");
    background-size: 200px 35px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 31px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

#users thead {
    background-image: url("_images/point_tr_head_back.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#users th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 9px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#users td {
    border: 2px solid #226fdb;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 18px 5px 2px 25px;
    line-height: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFFEE;
}
```

Note: Some of the styles used are likely unnecessary. I've been toying with it for a while and haven't cleaned it up yet.

SOLVED: further down if you would like to see the example. but put simply, wrap the content in a different element (like a span) and move all styles to the new element.

Comment: For better answers, you should share your code and if possible a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and [edit] your question with a [MRE] that include the minimum relevant HTML and CSS code needed to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Using :first-child and :last-child in combination with some CSS, I would think you should be able to style the thead th cells without an image. Then as others stated, using padding on the body items get where you want to be.

here is a quick example https://jsfiddle.net/vk4dygpx/

Comment: In ray's example below, I saw the use of the inset box shadow to create the image I created in inkscape. didn't even know it was a thing that could be done. I will certainly be switching to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could get there fairly easily with some margins and padding if you can wrap the cell contents in a span (or whatever).

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead tr {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 24px;
}

th {
  padding: 6px 1em;
}

th:first-child {
  border-radius: 24px 0 0 24px;
}

th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 24px 24px 0;
}


tbody td > span {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Xogue</span></td>
      <td><span>262677</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Jesse</span></td>
      <td><span>17632</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Nanokarp</span></td>
      <td><span>12344</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is why I say I am far from expert. Didn't even occur to me to add in a different element that allows the standard methods of spacing and apply everything to that.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add padding to your CSS for td only and keep rest of the attributes same among td and th as below, also if you can share the used code snippet someone can help better:

```
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but since I am attempting to use a background and border, this would extend the border and background, but still show the elements touch on the page.